# Get the previous month number including year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in which I get the coupons of a specific company. 
My coupon table is like:

Company_Coupon

- ID
- CompanyID
- Month
- Total_Coupons
- Year

I keep my months in the format of their number (1-12).

When I update the total coupons for the invoicing, I want to update the ones from the previous month.

I do this by the following query:

```
UPDATE Company_Coupon
SET Total_Coupons = @count
WHERE CompanyID = 1205
AND Month = MONTH(GETDATE())-1 AND Year  = YEAR (GETDATE())
```

My query works but I noticed that this won't work in January 2019.

How can I update this query so that it will work in January 2019?

Comment: It would probably be better to store a single `YearMonth` column, typed as `date` with a constraint enforcing that it's always the first day of the month. That way you can use straightforward date math functions to compute this. E.g. `DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010201',GETDATE()),'20010101')` always gives you the first of last month.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sadly this isn't an option at the moment since I use this table to loop through the rows and manipulate them using different algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with case when like below:

```
UPDATE Company_Coupon
SET Total_Coupons = @count
WHERE CompanyID = 1205
AND Month = (case when MONTH(GETDATE())-1=0 then 12 else MONTH(GETDATE())-1 end)  AND Year  = (case when MONTH(GETDATE())-1=0 then YEAR (GETDATE())-1 else YEAR (GETDATE()) end)
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't return the ones from december 2018 when I set `GETDATE()` to 2019-01-01

Comment: modified the answer..check now

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get different number between `1900-01-01` and your data, then do some calculation to get last month.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,'2019-01-01') - 1, 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,'2018-08-01') - 1, 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/33103/0)**:

```
|                      |
|----------------------|
| 2018-12-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z |
```

so you query can be

```
UPDATE Company_Coupon
SET Total_Coupons = @count
WHERE 
    CompanyID = 1205
AND 
    Month = MONTH(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
AND 
    Year  = YEAR (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I'd prefer to have a single `YearMonth` column with the correct data type for datetime work, but we can do something very similar here:

```
UPDATE Company_Coupon
SET Total_Coupons = @count
FROM Company_Coupon
CROSS APPLY (SELECT 
  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010201',GETDATE()),'20010101')) t(LastMonth)
WHERE CompanyID = 1205
AND Month = MONTH(LastMonth) AND Year  = YEAR(LastMonth)
```

The two dates used in the above expression do not matter much. All that matters really is the *relationship* between them. Here, the second date falls a month before the first and it's the relationship that effectively gets applied to `GETDATE()` by the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` expression. It's a pattern that can be used in lots of different ways - e.g. a variant of this pattern can be used to find the last day of 3 months ago if you're not on a SQL version that supports `EOMONTH`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or later version, you can employ the `eomonth()` function that returns last day of a previous month for a given date. From it, you can extract both `month()` and `year()` parts and use them in your query:

```
UPDATE c SET Total_Coupons = @count
from dbo.Company_Coupon c
WHERE c.CompanyID = 1205
    AND c.Month = MONTH(eomonth(GETDATE()))
    AND c.Year  = YEAR(eomonth(GETDATE()));
```